Getting HTTP status: 401 when displaying an image in Angular app from Web API backend
I am getting a status code: 401 in the console when trying to fetch and display an image from my ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API in my Angular 19 application. Please read the case scenario below, very closely and minutely.
I am uploading an image from my Angular application and it gets copied to a folder called RecipeImages under Resources in my Web API project structure, ie. the path is
WebAPI project --> Resources --> RecipeImages (images are copied here)

Simultaneously, I am saving the path in the database. The images are being copied to the desired path absolutely fine. The respective paths are also being saved in the database just fine.
An example of a saved path in the database is:

Resources\RecipeImages\Nigella_GarlicButterMushroom_638706726811613226.jpg

Note that the path is with backslashes. I followed the approach used in this tutorial to do the task:
https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/
Now I am trying to display this image in a component. Upon ngOnInit, I have written code to make a call to the backend service and get all the data from that database table. Fetching them and preparing the path to bind to the src attribute of the image control.
component.html:
<img [src]="createImagePath(selectedRecipeDetails.imagePath)" alt="" class="circular_recipe" style="height:410px; width: 410px;" />

component.ts:
createImagePath(path: any) {
  return `https://localhost:7164/${path}`;
}

When I am inspecting the blank/vacant image element on my page, the complete path that I am getting on the src attribute is as:
src="https://localhost:7164/Resources\RecipeImages\Nigella_GarlicButterMushroom_638706726811613226.jpg"

7164 is the port number on which my Web API backend is running. As you can see, there is a whole lot of mess with forward and backslashes.
I also made code changes in Program.cs so that my Web API backend can serve static files - like this:
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
    {
        opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerExplorer()
    .InjectDbContext(builder.Configuration)
    .AddAppConfig(builder.Configuration)
    .AddIdentityHandlersAndStores()
    .AddIdentityAuth(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();

var app = builder.Build();

app.ConfigureCORS(builder.Configuration)
    .ConfigureSwaggerExplorer()
    .AddIdentityAuthMiddlewares();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Basically, I did everything in toe-toe, with the tutorial. Still, I do not understand why I am unable to render the image in my component. I downloaded and ran the finished project from that tutorial to make sure that it was workable. It is!
But why there is an anomaly in my application? Goes without saying if I manually change all the backslashes in the saved path in the database to forward slashes, it still doesn't serve anything! My image control remains blank.
Can you folks spot anything? Any small detail that I may be overlooking? Or is there more code to be added/edited in the frontend and backend?
Please help sort this out!

If any of you want to cross verify, simply download from https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/dotnet-core-file-upload/tree/end-project       and run locally. Everything works there. Bizarrely! But for the life of me, I can't understand why it fails in my implementation!!

401 error means Unauthorized. This could be due to the request checks for permission before accessing the file. Did you implement any logic that requires permission to access the resource file? Did you try to paste the URL into browser to see whether you are able to view the file? And also it could be due to the ordering of the middleware in the pipeline (Program.cs) that the request is processed for authentication first instead of allowing the static resources. Would be great to share your complete Program.cs in the question.

If you determine that there is an issue in your code but not the shared repository, you should provide your code/repository to reproduce the error.

hi @YongShun I can't understand why it should return Unauthorized. Even the method that's returning the data from table including the imagepath is marked as Anonymous method. Yes, what you're saying that it could be due to ordering of middlewares in the Program.cs. It could be a possibility.
*** I haven't tried pasting the url in browser yet, but I am going to try it now and see if I can see the file. Do you have github profile? If yes, pls share, so that I can share my repository(private) with you. Also pls check my updated question post, I have added the Program.cs complete code to it.

Hey @YongShun IT'S WORKINGGG !! Yes!! You were correct. It WAS the order of configured middlewares in the Program.cs. Note the AddIdentityAuthMiddlewares() was appearing before the UseStaticFile configuration. I created a separate extension file & moved the  UseStaticFile code there & registered it BEFORE the AddIdentityAuthMiddlewares(). Ran project and VOILAA! My image is being served! You should have posted an answer instead of commenting so that I could have accepted & marked your answer as working! You have amazing analytical skills and understanding of things! I'm following you on Git !!

As mentioned in the comment, Middleware order affects how the request is processed.
From the link, the Static File Middleware (UseStaticFiles) should be placed before the CORS middleware (UseCors) and authentication and authorization middlewares.
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
});

app.ConfigureCORS(builder.Configuration)
   .ConfigureSwaggerExplorer()
   .AddIdentityAuthMiddlewares();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


ABSOLUTELY CORRECT !! You analysed the situation even without delving into code structure. Well Done @YongShun  !!
